# Are bloom effects possible for Java Graphics2D? If so, how?

Tags: java, graphics, shader, graphics2d, bloom

I've been attempting to make a 2D space-like game using Java just for the fun of it. I've decided just to use Java's Graphics2D to render my game because I wasn't in the mood to learn LWJGL. However, I just now realized how limited it is. For example, I realized a nice bloom/glow effect would look really nice. However, I can't find anything on Google about doing so with Graphics2D and without using another library.

What bloom effect I'm looking for:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18594/how-can-i-make-this-style-of-2d-glowing-graphics

Bloom information:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28shader_effect%29

#### So the main question is, does anyone know of a good method to add a sharp bloom shader effect using Graphics2D?

Comment: The closest thing I can think of would be to create an effect using ConvolveOp with custom matrices.  If you play around with that a bit, you should be able to create something similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone else reading this question - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_%28shader_effect%29

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc Apologies, I should have been more detailed about everything.

Comment: @Josh1billion To be fair, IIRC doing a convolution with a custom matrix describes about half of all common image processing operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no **bloom effect** ready for use available in the Java 2D API, but it is certainly possible to implement one.

- First, I suggest you investigate how such filters work and for that I recommend taking a look at [Jerry's Java Image Processing Pages](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/index.html). There are [many filter implementations](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) available on that page for [download](http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/download.html).
- There's an interesting discussion about the *bloom effect* on [Java2D Bloom](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=26932.0), and they share source code.
- There's also a nice comparison of a *bloom effect* implemented in Java and GLSL at [Fast Image Processing with JOGL](http://www.curious-creature.org/2007/02/20/fast-image-processing-with-jogl/):

[image]

Comment: Java2D Bloom link broken.

Comment: @user207421 Not surprised, after all, it's a 10+ years old answer. The Wayback Machine doesn't have a copy of that page but one can find [interesting stuff](https://jvm-gaming.org/t/java2d-bloom/39353/14) searching on Google.